# Box positioning - cross-browser compatibility issue

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with a page layout on the website I am working on.

Here's a [link](http://goo.gl/Q5Y0vh)

The blue box on the right hand side is looking good in IE and Firefox, but it's too short (the text is too close to the bottom of the box) in Chrome, Safari and Opera.

Here's the code for the box:

```
#testimon {
   background: url("../img/ttm_bg.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
   border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
   border-top: 4px groove #00D1FA;
   box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 1px #555555;
   font-size: 14px;
   height: 788px;
   margin-top: 26px;
   padding: 3px;
   text-align: center;
   width: 262px;
 }
#testimon h4 {
   color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.92);
   font-size: 19px;
   margin: 8px 0 17px 0;
   text-shadow: 1px 2px 2px #1A1A1A;
 }
#testimon p {
   font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
   color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.88);
   line-height:25px;
   font-size: 14px;
   font-style: oblique;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #CCCCCC;
 }
#testimon .quote {
   font-size:25px;
   padding:4px;
 }
#testimon .signature {
   color: #e6e6e6;
   font-style: normal;
   margin-bottom: 15px;
   text-shadow: none;
 }
#testimon .spacer2 {
   background: url("../img/stars.png") no-repeat scroll 98px 0 transparent;
   height: 13px;
   margin: 31px 0 15px 0;
   width: 262px;
 }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I've compared FF and Chrome and that one and couldn't see any difference. The version of Chrome you're using and a picture of the problem will be helpful

Comment: Also, ALWAYS reset the way browsers should display the element using: `-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;` which will make the box model same across all browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is less a cross-browser issue and more a styling issue - you've got a fixed height on that testimonials div, so what if someone has different fonts than you specify, or increases the font size on their browser, the text will spill over (as it did when I upped the font using Firebug).

The solution is to remove the `height` from the `#testimon` element, and ensure that the background repeats vertically (which it currently does not).

Comment: I'm not even sure why a background image is being used here myself.  I would just set `background-color: #039ED6;`.

Comment: @cale_b Thank you, that helped! I just noticed one more issue with my site, in FF I see 1px break between the menu and wrapper, but when I increase the text size that gap disappears and all looks good, in other browsers that break appears after increasing the text size, so it's the opposite, any ideas what may cause that?

Comment: @user2664401 - I'm not seeing the break, I assume you got it worked out.

Comment: @cale_b - not really, It's still there, did you try to increase/decrease the font size of the browser to 90% or 110%? That's when it shows up

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a font rendering related issue.  The sizes are slightly different in each browser so the end overall height is different.  I would remove the `height` value from `#testimon`.

Answer (score 0):

I look at the site with Crome, Opera, Maxathon, Firefox, Safari, and I.E., all browsers are current version of the browser. The images and the text look good. The only issue I could see were in some of the browsers you had to click on the image two or maybe three times to make the image to zoom in.

You might want to clear the cache of the browser and close and re-open the browser.

Comment: what do you mean click two or three times? It is not responding on hover? or loading so slow?